# Turning the computer off from the terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

How can I shutdown my computer from the command line?
I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I tried using `shutdown` but it does not work.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/187071/how-do-i-restart-shutdown-from-a-terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must type:

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```